# Test Suite in Flask with MongoEngine

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mongoengine, test-suite

I have a small app in Flask which I want to accompany with tests. I have used Django tests before, and I'm just getting to grips with the lower level functionality in Flask.

My tests currently look like this:

```
import unittest
from config import app
from mongoengine import connect
from my_app.models import User

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config["MONGODB_DB"] = 'xxx'
        connect(
            'xxx',
            username='heroku',
            password='xxx',
            host='xxx',
            port=xxx
        )
        self.app = app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_create_user(self):
        u = User(username='john', email='john@example.com')
        u.save()
```

I know that this is wrong, because the test passes but I have added an entry into the database. How should I test the creation of a User without polluting the database? I had assumed that `app.config['TESTING']` had some significance here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two approaches I know of:

**1. Separate Test Database**

This is something that Django does automatically for unittesting.  It simply uses a separate database for testing that it clears before and after every test run.  You could implement something like this manually.

**2. Use Mocking to avoid actually using the database**

This is the more preferred method for most situations. You use mocking to simulate various functions so that the tests don't actually create/edit/delete information in a real database.  This is better for multiple reasons, most notably for performance/speed of your unit tests.

Comment: Great. I was coming to this conclusion - I have been used to Djago providing the 'magic'. Are there any good mocking libraries out there for Flask?

Comment: You can use any python mock library (for example `mock`), but for database better find some package thats already mocking `mongoengine` or `pymongo`. Look at another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16017141/880326.

Comment: Mocking a better solution? You must be joking. Mocking is fantastic to avoid API calls, speed up testing (single-layer testing) and tons of stuff, but using it to avoid creating stuff in the DB is like test-driving a car without sitting on it. No. Solution 1 the right one in this case.