# Connecting to external dummy MongoDB server

Tags: mongodb

To [run Meteor without Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545905/meteor-without-mongo), a dummy MongoDB server is needed. Obviously, one solution is to run `mongod` locally, or launch a [mock MongoDB server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915031/use-mock-mongodb-server-for-unit-test).

What other ways are there to connect to a dummy MongoDB server for testing purposes?

Any Mongo hosting providers that have put up a dummy/test server, basically a `/dev/null` over `mongodb://`?

Answer (score 2):

[mongolab](https://mongolab.com/plans/) has that in their free sandbox level.

[compose.io](https://www.compose.io/pricing/) also has a free sandbox level.

search for 'mongo sandbox' or 'mongo free'.

the local mongo (on osx) is invaluable; don't know about wind blows.